# How to show border around image which is clipped by the surrounding div

Tags: html, css

I have an image as shown below:

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="diamond-border" style="left:10px;top:10px"></div>
<div class="diamond" style="left:13px;top:13px" >
  <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg" />
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
.diamond
{
  background-color: white;
  height: 260px;
  width: 260px;
  position: absolute;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);  
}

.diamond-border
{
  background-color: #AAA;
  height: 266px;
  width: 266px;
  position: absolute;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
}

.diamond img
{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

**What I want:**

I want to show the border around image as follows:

[image]

**What I tried for that:**

```
img
{
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

But the border is not showing. How do I show that border?

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Vishal1419/gfok1bv8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a div with same height and width as your image to wrap that code and give it a border.
here is updated code from your fiddle

```
<div class="diamond-container">
   <div class="diamond-border" style="left:10px;top:10px"></div>
   <div class="diamond" style="left:13px;top:13px" >
      <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg" />
   </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
    .diamond
{
  background-color: white;
  height: 260px;
  width: 260px;
  position: absolute;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);  
}

.diamond-border
{
  background-color: #AAA;
  height: 266px;
  width: 266px;
  position: absolute;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
}

.diamond img
{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
.diamond-container{
  border: 5px solid red;
  height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

here is an updated fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/icernn03/gfok1bv8/3/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css transform property to achieve that. check this fiddle:

```
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ggukk60j/

Comment: Nope. You misunderstood my question. I don't want to rotate the image. I just want to show border around the image.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use a wrapper :**

```css
#wrapper {
 border:5px solid red;
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
}
 

.diamond
{
  background-color: white;
  height: 260px;
  width: 260px;
  position: absolute;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);  
}

.diamond-border
{
  background-color: #AAA;
  height: 266px;
  width: 266px;
  position: absolute;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
}

.diamond img
{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

    <div class="diamond-border" style="left:10px;top:10px"></div>

    <div class="diamond" style="left:13px;top:13px" >
   <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg" />
     </div>

</div>
```